Expo Build Hangs at 98-99% in WSL Home Directory but Works on Windows Mount
I’m working on an Expo project within WSL 2 (Ubuntu) on a Windows 11 machine, and I’m encountering a strange issue:
When I run npx expo start --clear on my project located in the Windows mount (/mnt/c/...), the build works perfectly, and I can connect to my phone without any issues. Unfortunately, watchdog/expo does not detect file changes in this set up. One solution suggested online is to move it to the wsl ubuntu home directory instead.
However, when I run the exact same command on the project located in my WSL home directory (~/...), the build gets stuck at 98% (or sometimes 25%). I don’t get any error messages, just the hang.
This behavior seems to differ based on the file location (Windows mount vs. WSL home directory). I suspect it might be related to how WSL handles the file system, but I'm not sure what exactly is causing it.
I am running WSL with networkingMode=mirrored as I was not able to connect with my IOS Device without it.
Steps Taken:

Tried running with --clear to avoid caching issues.
Confirmed that the build works fine on the Windows-mounted directory (/mnt/c/...).
Firewall is open for the needed ports


I had the same problem, I reinstalled expo from scratch and it worked

Delete the .expo folder located here /home/[username]/.expo
Reinstall Expo using yarn add expo

Then the npx expo start command should work again
